# Adding Vertical Space between Line Breaks

Tags: html, css

This seems like a common CSS question, but for some reason I cannot find the answer to it.

consider the following Code:

```
<div style="width:50px;border:1px solid #000">
    THis is a looooooooong text. and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on
    <br/>
    2nd line
    <br/>
    3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 
    <br/>
    last line
</div>
```

With **CSS ONLY** I want to add vertical space between the `<br/>` tags.

line-height works for the entire content, and attaching CSS to `<br>` (i.e: br{ margin:10px 0}), doesn't seem to work either (in Chrome at least), so I am wondering if this is even possible.

Thank you.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CCUsK/2/)

​

Comment: is there a reason you can't just put <br/><br/>  ?

Comment: I have no control over the content. That's why I wrote CSS only. and no javascript is allowed either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
br
{
    content: " " !important;
    display: block !important;
    margin:30px;
}
```

​try this

Comment: Bad idea.  Don't use "content".   Its CSS-3 specific, and its awkward.  Getting the <br> tag to act like a stylable block is what you want.

Comment: @Jim do you have a better way of doing this? As far as I can tell that's the only way given the constraints OP has.

Comment: This works. Although the answer given by Mr. Alien is much cleaner. I awarded this to Sen Jacob, since he answered first. No need for the "!important" tags and content can be content:"". Thanks.

Comment: @Sammy I too support Alien's answer :)

Comment: I guess I mis-spoke or haven't fooled with this for too long. I was 99% certain this could be done without 'content' without any difficulty, but it wasn't able to get it quickly in fiddle.  Anyway, hey if content works then it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, works on chrome too, `content: " "` does the trick for chrome, else is happy with margins

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CCUsK/15/)

HTML

```
<div>
    THis is a looooooooong text. and it goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on
    <br/>
    2nd line
    <br/>
    3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 3rd line 
    <br/>
    last line
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
}

br {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

​
​

Comment: Bad idea.  Its css 3 specific and its awkward.  You're adding content to something that should be considered style oriented.  Getting the BR tag to act like a block element or use proper padding is what you want.  Content property is a hack.  You shouldn't have to hack this.

Comment: @PerfectDark this is the best I could get, or else I would suggest to use javascript instead or using a div and giving a height to it

Comment: @Jim dude, sometimes bad thing is good, read adaptive design book, you'll get me, this was a solution, how clean you want to go is upto you than

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.  There are several issues related that you need to understand.

1) You're using margins. Sometimes margins will be collapsed or removed depending on content.  Have you tried using padding instead?  You will get different results.  I don't have any direct links off hand but google around and make sure you understand the important differences between margins and padding.

2) Learn about the box-models.  If you don't know about box-model: border-box, then you need to go study it.  Chris Coyier of css-tricks.com has an article on it.  I'm pointing it out because its directly pertinent to issues like this one.

3) display:block   I don't know for certain but I think 
 probably defaults to display: inline.  You can any element it and always make it act like a standard block DIV if you set display: block as one of the properties.  Again, Chris Coyier has some great information on this.  Please make sure you have a deep appreciation  of display: rules and their caveats.

Just adding display:  block and either using margins or padding will fix your problem.  If it doesn't, there's something stupid simply I'm missing.  I've done this type of thing before.  In fact, I've completely removed 
 tags from Wordpress theme markups using display: none to completely reformat image gallery outputs.